# Haskell type families, understanding error message

Tags: haskell, type-families

Upon trying to use [`Data.Has`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/has/0.5.0.1/doc/html/Data-Has.html), I've been writing code like the following:

```
data Name = Name; type instance TypeOf Name = Text
type NameRecord = FieldOf Name;
```

I've found:

```
instance I NameRecord where
  ...
```

Throws a compile error, namely:

> Illegal type synonym family application in instance

Whereas:

```
instance (NameRecord ~ a) => I a where
  ...
```

Compiles fine.

I believe the error is related to [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3485) ticket in GHC, marked as invalid.

The response to the ticket says:

> I am not sure what you are suggesting. We cannot automatically
>   transform
>
> ```
> instance C (Fam Int) -- (1)
> ```
>
> into
>
> ```
> instance (Fam Int ~ famint) => C famint -- (2)
> ```
>
> This works if there is only one instance, but as soon as there are two
>   such instances, they always overlap.
>
> Maybe you are suggesting that we should do it anyway and programmers
>   should just take the implicit transformation into account. I don't
>   think that this is a good idea. It's confusing for very little benefit
>   (as you can always write the transformed instance yourself with little
>   effort).

Can someone elaborate on this explanation, perhaps with some sample code where the (1) fails but (2) does not, and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A case where (1) fails but (2) does not is trivial; because type synonyms (`type ExampleOfATypeSynonym = ...`) are not allowed in instance declarations, but they are allowed in constraints, any situation where you have only **one** instance like this:

```
-- (1)
class Foo a
type Bla = ()
instance Foo Bla
```

... can be transformed into:

```
-- (2)
class Foo a
type Bla = ()
instance (a ~ Bla) => Foo a
```

The only reason why (1) fails is because type synonyms are not allowed in instance declarations, and that's because type synonyms are like type functions: they provide a one-way mapping from a type name to a type name, so if you have a `type B = A` and an `instance Foo B`, it is non-obvious that an instance of `Foo A` is created instead. The rule exists so that you have to write `instance Foo A` instead to make it clear that *that* is the type that actually gets the instance.

The use of type families is irrelevant in this context, because the problem is rather that you're using a type synonym, the `NameRecord` type. You have to also keep in mind that if the type synonym is removed and replaced by `FieldOf Name` directly, the compile will still fail; that is because a "type family" is just an enhanced version of type synonyms, so `FieldOf Name` is also a "type synonym" for `Name :> Text` in this context. You have to use a data family and a data instance instead to get a "bidirectional" association.

More information about data families can be found in the [GHC documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/type-families.html#data-families).

---

I think you mean "... where (2) fails but (1) does not..."

Let's imagine that we have a type class like so:

```
class Foo a where
  foo :: a
```

Now, you can write instances like so:

```
 instance Foo Int where
   foo = 0

 instance Foo Float where
   foo = 0

 main :: IO ()
 main = print (foo :: Float)
```

This works as one would expect. However, if you transform the code into this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, TypeFamilies #-}
class Foo a where
  foo :: a

instance (a ~ Int) => Foo a where
  foo = 0

instance (a ~ Float) => Foo a where
  foo = 0

main :: IO ()
main = print (foo :: Float)
```

It doesn't compile; it displays the error:

```
test.hs:5:10:
    Duplicate instance declarations:
      instance a ~ Int => Foo a -- Defined at test.hs:5:10-27
      instance a ~ Float => Foo a -- Defined at test.hs:8:10-29
```

So, this is the example you hopefully were looking for. Now, this only happens if there is more than one instance of `Foo` that uses this trick. Why is that?

When GHC resolves type classes, it only looks at the instance declaration head; i.e. it ignores everything before the `=>`. When it has chosen an instance, it "commits" to it, and checks the constraints before the `=>` to see whether they are true. So, at first it sees two instances:

```
instance Foo a where ...
instance Foo a where ...
```

It is clearly impossible to decide which instance to use based on this information alone.

Comment: Out of interest, do you happen to know if GHC's method of resolving type classes is an explicit design decision? And if so, the reason for it? (Or maybe the alternative is just too complicated to implement cleanly?)

Comment: The reason for it is that the Haskell Report requires it to behave like this. The reason for **that** is that if it didn't behave like this, there'd have to be an algorithm that gave a heuristic for "how well a type fits a constraint;" you'd have to argue "Yeah, this type fits this class instance, but that other instance fits much better because {less constraints, shorter reduction distance, ...}." It might be possible to develop such a heuristic, but it would break the Open World Assumption which is a key concept when it comes to type classes.

Comment: Imagine `instance String ~ a => Foo a` and `instance a ~ [b] => Foo a`. That's an example of instances where you'd need an algorithm to resolve `Foo [Char]`.

Comment: Ah, interesting, thanks! So the reason is basically: it violates OWA and so breaks some of the nice properties of type classes. (On a slightly tangential note, CSS has various rules to explicitly work out which selectors are "more important" and override others, so such a heuristic is possible (and useable).)

Comment: @dflemstr: No, I think I meant (1) fails but (2) does not. Did you view the GHC ticket I linked to in the article, and can you refer to it in your answer?

Comment: @dflemstr: Keep in mind that `Data.Has` which I linked to uses "type families" under the hood (as indicated by the title), which I feel may effect this. If you believe they're irrelevant here, can you mention why?

Comment: I have expanded my answer to include an explanation for this.

Comment: @dflemstr: Thanks for your reply, it's been very helpful. I've realised perhaps I've missed the point of my question, now that you've given me a better understanding of how instances are checked, particularly clashes. I've asked a new related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491521/haskell-instance-definitions-for-type-families