# Haskell: Instance definitions for type families

Tags: haskell, type-families

Lets say we have the following code:

```
class C t where
  g :: t

instance C Int where
  g = 42
```

Simple. We can also define functions on Int, like so:

```
f1 :: Int -> Int
f1 x = x * x
```

I've been working with type families, in particular because [`Data.Has`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/has/0.5.0.1/doc/html/Data-Has.html) uses them, and I want to insert them into an [`IxSet`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/ixset/1.0.2/doc/html/Data-IxSet.html).

But here I'm going to present a simplified example. Lets say we want to define a new type `X`, that is similar to an Int. We could do this:

```
type family X
type instance X = Int
```

We can then define functions on `X` like so:

```
f2 :: X -> X
f2 x = x * x + 1
```

No problems so far. Now lets try to define an instance `C X`, like we did for `C Int`:

```
instance C X where
  g = 43
```

Uh oh, now we have the following error:

> Illegal type synonym family application in instance: `X`
>   In the instance declaration for `'C X'`

Now lets try something a bit different:

```
newtype NewX = NewX X

instance C NewX where
  g = 43
```

Now we've got another error, namely:

> No instance for `(Num NewX)`
>     arising from the literal `'43'`

It seems like the `newtype` keyword eliminates any information about what classes the previous class belonged too. However, it also seems I can't avoid `newtype`, as I can't use type families in instance definitions.

Is there a better way to do this without having to rewrite instance definitions with additional explicit instances mentions which otherwise would be inferred?

---

***Background information:***

The reason why I need this to work is the following:

```
import Data.Has
import Data.IxSet

data Col1 = Col1; type instance TypeOf Col1 = Text
data Col2 = Col2; type instance TypeOf Col2 = Text

type Row = FieldOf Col1 :&: FieldOf Col2;

instance Indexable Row where
  empty = ixSet [ixFun $ (\x -> [ Col1 ^. x ]) ] -- Maybe add some more indexes later
```

This fails with:

> Illegal type synonym family application in instance: `Row`
>   In the instance declaration for `'Indexable Row'`

Making `Row` a `newtype` causes the following error:

> No instance for (Contains (Labelled Col1 Text) Row)
>     arising from a use of `^.'
>   Possible fix:
>     add an instance declaration for
>     (Contains (Labelled Col1 Text) Row)

The only way I can work around this is by adding a long deriving clause as follows:

```
newtype Row = Row (FieldOf Col1 :&: FieldOf Col2)
  deriving 
  (
    Contains (Labelled Col1 Text), -- Add this for every column
    Contains (Labelled Col2 Text)  -- ...
  )
```

Even something which allows me to "typedef" `Contains (Labelled x (TypeOf x))` to say `HasCol x` would be helpful.

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to do. Type synonyms are not allowed in instance heads, and `X` is a synonym for `Int` (kind of). However you just can use the original type instead (`Int` in this case). Perhaps a more real example would clarify the picture.

Comment: @n.m. I've added some background information to my question.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not evaluating `Row` yourself and writing an instance for that type, instead?

Comment: @DanielWagner: What do you mean?

Comment: It looks like the problem is with the regular type synonyms, not type instances. `-XTypeSynonymInstances -XFlexibleInstances` might be what you need.

Comment: @n.m.: Can you elaborate? What will work if I use `TypeSynonymInstances` and `FlexibleInstances`?

Comment: I mean: go into ghci and use `:kind! Row` to work out the actual type you want to declare an instance for and declare an instance for that instead.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Sorry, I still don't understand, could you give some sample code?

Comment: No, I can't give some sample code, because that would require understanding the `has` and `ixset` packages. I'm not going to spend the time to learn what they do and how to use them if you're not going to spend the time to learn what `:kind!` does and why that's useful.

Comment: Sorry, these options don't help because `:&:` *is* a type family.

Comment: @DanielWagner: I don't need sample code with `has` and `ixset`. A simple example with you own code would be fine, I'll work out how to apply it to `has` and `ixset`. I particularly didn't understand what you meant by "to work out the actual type you want to declare an instance for and declare an instance for that instead". I thought some simple code (with dummy classes X, Y etc) would help illustrate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `newtype` does just that--it defines a new type, while a `type` defines a synonym.  If you dont like a bunch of deriving clauses, one can always use the isomorphism with the underlying type

```
instance C NewX where
   g = NewX  43
```

the reason type synonyms dont play nice with Instance declarations, is that functions (including type functions) only work in one direction.  You can only pattern match on constructors, so `newtype` allows you to introduce a new type constructor at zero runtime cost.  In your problem, why not

```
newtype Row = Row {runRow :: FieldOf Col1 :&: FieldOf Col2}

instance Indexable Row where
  empty = ixSet [ixFun $ (\x -> [ Col1 ^. (runRow x) ]) ]
```

I should note that in general `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` is unsound.  Doesn't mean you should avoid using it, but does imply what you want is probably impossible.

---

***Edit (Question asker):***

Better yet, no need to even change the data type Row

```
newtype Row = Row ( FieldOf Col1 :&: FieldOf Col2 )

instance Indexable Row where
  empty = ixSet [ixFun $ (\(Row x) -> [ Col1 ^. x ]) ]
```

Comment: This seems to do the job, thanks! Though I'll keep the question open in case there is an answer that doesn't require the indirection of the field `runRow` (even if it has zero runtime cost).

Comment: I've added another change, this seems to do the trick, with minimal additional code. I think this is the answer (it was much simpler than I thought!)

Answer (score 5):

The following file compiles here:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, TypeFamilies #-}

class C a where g :: a
type family X
type instance X = Int
newtype NewX = NewX X deriving Num
instance C NewX where g = 43
```

Comment: Thanks! I presume there is no `deriving EVERYTHING` style thing (a way to make `NewX` basically a copy of `X`)?

Comment: Do you know a better way to solve my issue given the background information I have added to the question?